# How can I make a rounded indentation on a cylinder? (Cosmetic Plastic Bottle Lid)

Tags: mesh, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to do a cosmetic bottle in blender but i don't how to do this thing in the image. How to do this round edge on the cap. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Why this question is downvoted so much? It's pretty hard topology concern...

Comment: I tried to find a tutorial and tried to do it myself but i can't. I guess it's a good question and will help other people.

Comment: Thanks you cegaton for the edit. Never heard of the word indentation before.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44982/modeling-flat-surface-shapes-on-a-cylinder/44986#44986

Comment: Tomorrow I'll make an answer with nice quad proper topology.

Comment: Apart from Boolean Inset and then scaling inwards along normals (Alt+S) can do that.

Answer (score 22):

Though you may do it using *Boolean Modifier* (or *BoolTool* add on) the good solution here may be using an ***Inset tool*** since it'll allow you to make a clean topology mesh.
[image]

Add a *cylinder* with 16 subdivisions. Add edge loops <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to define the indentation position. Select the faces representing the indentation and press <kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>B</kbd> (to enable Boundary mode). Repeat it twice (to create the extra edge loops for subsurf creasing). Extrude it inwards (<kbd>E</kbd>), then inset again as before.
[image]

Add the additional edge loops to the indent, then form its shape transforming some vertices. Finally fill the top part of the *cylinder* with mesh (example topology pictured in the first .jpeg).
[image]

Comment: Damn, I wish I could upvote twice. Years using Blender now and I didn't know about that *Boundary Mode* for the *Inset* operator, that second GIF caught my eye. Life saver, insanely useful when working near the symmetry axis with the *Mirror* modifier. Thanks for this!

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos Thanks for kind words. You have no idea how often I discover obvious/basic blender tools after many years :).

Answer (score 1):

To answer to Kosmani's question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254392/how-to-create-this-cosmetic-tube-lid#254392), which is about a slightly different lid:

[image]

You can begin with a 32 vertex cylinder and 16/8 vertex sphere that you'll use as a boolean object:

[image]

Apply the *Boolean*, add some horizontal edges with the knife tool:

[image]

Rearrange the topology a bit, give your object a *Solidify* modifier:

[image]

Apply the *Solidify*, bevel the edges in order to sharpen when you'll give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]