# Bevel unexpected result

Tags: modeling, mesh, bevel

after a boolean operation I was trying to bevel some edges, the result is completely random, any idea how deal with this?
My ideal result would be [something like this](https://github.com/fedackb/yavne)

[link to the file](http://www.filedropper.com/bevelerror)

Thank you!

[image: Weird bevel behaviour]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a rounded indentation on a cylinder?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81596/how-can-i-make-a-rounded-indentation-on-a-cylinder)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of your face is reversed, you need to recalculate the normals (in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>).

I guess it messed up with the bevel because bevel uses the orientation to create the bevel profile, so two faces with opposite normal orientation > bug.

Anyway, here is a way to do it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But unfortunately my problem comes with the "create bevel" step, the vertices go in random directions...

Comment: so maybe share your file

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully you can find a solution.
Btw thank you for your detailed explanation with images, much appreciated!

Comment: Oh thanks, actually you just need to recalculate the normals

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But I wonder why they use normals and not the the actual face orientation to bevel...

Comment: I guess it messed up with the bevel because bevel uses the orientation to create the bevel profile, so two faces with opposite normal orientation > bug