# Black parts in model texture

Tags: texturing

I am experiencing a issue in my 3d blender model.
It seems as if hard shadows are appearing on my model, but it is not a lighting issue as when I add a sun lamp the black spots are still there as seen below.

[image]

It is also not an overlapping issue as i can find no overlapping quads over my whole model. I will leave the blender model below so that you can look at it yourselves and hopefully fix this issue :)
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post use the tools form this site load images, so that they are displayed directly on the question and not as link.

Comment: Auto smooth is turned on. Turn it off and it will look fine (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133573/smooth-shading-artifacts)