# How to create this Cosmetic Tube Lid with half round hole

Tags: extrude

How can i modulate this lid?

Bolean Modifier or better with extruding a Hole in a Cylinder?

Thank you for your good support! :)

[image]

Comment: In the page linked by Duarte I've added a solution that fits your shape

Comment: Wow thank you very very much!